# Error while installing AMD GPU Driver | amdgpu-lib32 dependencies not met | trying to set up ROCm

Tags: amdgpu, tensorflow

I am using Linux Kernel 6.2.0-23-generic, Ubuntu 23.04, and an AMD Radeon RX 7900 XT (not XTX!).

I have 3 monitors plugged into my PC, 2 of them via a Display Port to HDMI converter and one directly plugged into the HDMI port on my GPU. The two using the DP-HDMI converter don't turn on anymore. I was originally trying to set up ROCm for TensorFlow and while following the installation process according to the [official AMD documentation](https://docs.amd.com/bundle/ROCm-Getting-Started-Guide-v5.3/page/How_to_Install_ROCm.html), when I was asked to reboot my PC, only one of the monitors turned on and I have not been able to fix it. Research suggested to simply uninstall and reinstall all drivers but now I ran into the following Problem:

```
mentrix@mentrix:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install ./amdgpu-install_5.4.50406-1_all.deb 
[...]
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/mentrix/Downloads/amdgpu-install_5.4.50406-1_all.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

Followed by:

```
mentrix@mentrix:~/Downloads$ amdgpu-install -y --accept-eula
[...]
linux-headers-6.2.0-23-generic is already the newest version (6.2.0-23.23).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libllvm-amdgpu:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 but it is not installable or
                         libwayland-client0:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 but it is not installable or
                         libwayland-server0:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:i386 but it is not installable or
                         libwayland-egl1:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 but it is not installable
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
[...]
Reading package lists... Done
```

As far as I understand, I need to install amdgpu-lib32 but the dependencies are not available. I already had set this up once, doing it exactly as I did now, when I first set up my PC on Ubuntu 23.04 and everything worked fine. Now, for some reason, it does not work and I don't know what to do anymore.

I have been trying to set up my PC to use my GPU with TensorFlow for 8 weeks now and I've already lost about all nerves I had along the way. It would be awesome if anybody here is able to help me set this up properly. All I want is that my GPU outputs an image to my 3 monitors again and shows up in TensorFlow using ROCm.

Help is much appreciated! Thank you! <3